# Conditional Formatting based on layout view

Tags: database, layout, conditional-statements, filemaker

Another question for you Filemaker Pro experts. The database I am developing starts with a *Main* layout with a number of buttons (e.g. insert new item, show all items, etc.). Each button is associated to a script, which takes the user to the relevant layout. In each of these layouts I show the buttons in a row, and highlight the current layout with inverse colour.
My problem is that some of the buttons lead to the same layout, viewed in different modes, and I don't know how to conditionally highlight the right button.

For instance, *Insert new item* and *Show all items* take to the same layout, however in the first case the script views the layout as a form and inserts a new record, while in the second I view as a list and show all records. The layout is the same, though, so I'd need to enact a conditional formatting based on something. How do I do that, and what should I check against?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are currently using the formula: `Get (LayoutName)` to decide on your conditional formula, why not try additionally using formulas: [`Get(WindowMode)`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref2.32.88.html#1032114) and [`Get(LayoutViewState)`](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref2.32.44.html#1030154)?

You could conditionally format the button if (which sends user to MyLayout in browse mode):

```
Get(WindowMode)=0 and Get(LayoutName)="MyLayout"
```

Or (which sends user to MyLayout in form view):

```
Get(LayoutViewState)=0 and Get(LayoutName)="MyLayout"
```

.

Other functions which may help could be `Get(FoundCount)` and `Get(TotalRecordCount)`. *You can see the entire list of `Get` functions [here](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref2.32.1.html#1030154).*